# In CMake how do I deal with generated source files which number and names are not known before?

Tags: cmake, dependencies, code-generation

Imagine a code generator which reads an input file (say a UML class diagram) and produces an **arbitrary number** of source files which I want to be handled in my project. (to draw a simple picture let's assume the code generator just produces `.cpp` files).

The problem is now the number of files generated depends on the input file and thus is not known when writing the `CMakeLists.txt` file or even in CMakes configure step. E.g.:

```
>>> code-gen uml.xml
generate class1.cpp..
generate class2.cpp..
generate class3.cpp..
```

What's the recommended way to handle generated files in such a case? You could use `FILE(GLOB.. )` to collect the file names after running `code-gen` the first time but this is discouraged because CMake would not know any files on the first run and later it would not recognize when the number of files changes.

I could think of some approaches but I don't know if CMake covers them, e.g.:

- (somehow) define a dependency from an input file (`uml.xml` in my example) to a variable (list with generated file names)
- in case the code generator can be convinced to tell which files it generates the output of `code-gen` could be used to create a list of input file names. (would lead to similar problems but at least I would not have to use `GLOB` which might collect old files)
- just define a custom target which runs the code generator and handles the output files without CMake (don't like this option)

**Update:** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076307/cmake-globbing-generated-files) question targets a similar problem but just asks how to *glob* generated files which does not address how to re-configure when the input file changes.

Comment: Have you checked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076307/cmake-globbing-generated-files? It describes the situation similar to yours one.

Comment: I normally re-implement the naming logic of the generator in my CMake script (reading the input file and parsing it to get the information). Can you please give an example of the `uml.xml` content? Which UML tool are you using?

Comment: This tool is just fictitious - I'm interested in the general approach. The problem is that the content of such a file might change so CMake would have to re-configure in such a case.

Comment: `... which does not address how to re-configure when the input file changes.` - Reconfiguration on file change is asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246037/how-to-make-cmake-reconfiguration-depend-on-custom-file. This aspect is also noted in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44078192/3440745).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222326/cmake-compiling-generated-files/39258996#39258996.

Answer (score 2):

Together with Tsyvarev's answer and some more googling I came up with the following `CMakeList.txt` which does what I want:

```
project(generated)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
set(IN_FILE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/input.txt")
set_property(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${IN_FILE}")
execute_process(
    COMMAND python3 "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/code-gen" "${IN_FILE}"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
    INPUT_FILE "${IN_FILE}"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE GENERATED_FILES
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
add_executable(generated main.cpp ${GENERATED_FILES})
```

It turns an input file (`input.txt`) into output files using `code-gen` and compiles them.

`execute_process` is being executed in the configure step and the `set_property()` command makes sure CMake is being re-run when the input file changes.

Note: in this example the code-generator must print a CMake-friendly list on `stdout` which is nice if you can modify the code generator. `FILE(GLOB..)` would do the trick too but this would for sure lead to problems (e.g. old generated files being compiled, too, colleagues complaining about your code etc.)

**PS**: I don't like to answer my own questions - If you come up with a nicer or cleaner solution in the next couple of days I'll take yours!