# CMake : add executable with unknown genererated source files

Tags: cmake

I have a tool that generates a set source files whose name I am not able to know beforehand.

How to write a proper CMakeLists.txt script for scenario? This question has been asked before here [CMake Compiling Generated Files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4222326/2912478). But it does not have a proper solution.

For instance, in the first answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748478/2912478), OP can predict which files will generated based on the input `.idl` files. The second answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39258996/2912478) shows three different ways to solve but I really couldn't get his solution working.

## Test case

I prepared a simple test case. Suppose I have this static file where the main resides (`main.cpp`).

```cpp
# main.cpp
void foo(void);

int main() {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Currently, I am using this `CMakeLists.txt`. The custom command generates the source file under `src`.

```
# CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(a.out  main.cpp)

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT mylib.cpp
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/genf.sh ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src
  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/genf.sh
)
add_custom_target(GenFile DEPENDS mylib.cpp)
add_dependencies(a.out GenFile)
```

Here is the hypothetical code generator `genf.sh`. I use a random number to mimic the fact that we do NOT know which files the generator will generate.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf $1/*
fname=$(echo $((1 + RANDOM % 100)))
echo "Generating src$fname.cpp"
echo "void foo(void) {}" > $1/src$fname.cpp
```

## Attempt 1

I tried to use GLOB to find all files generated. So I put the following lines at the end of my `CMakeLists.txt`. This doesn't work because at the moment of running `cmake ..` there is no files under src. So this solution never links the generated source files.

```
file(GLOB GeneratedSourceFiles ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)
target_sources(a.out PUBLIC ${GeneratedSourceFiles})
```

Comment: There is no other way than specifying all source files for `add_executable`. If you can collect this list only after creating these files, then you need to create them before `add_executable`, e.g. with `execute_process` call.

Comment: @Tsyvarev That makes a lot of sense.